# I need an exact cut

Tags: objects

[image]

I am fairly new to blender so I am having a difficult time explaining this but I need to cut completely through this object, level with the the top of the brackets.

Then I need to be able to have both pieces filled in so I can make them separate objects.

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain how to do this in depth, as I stated before i am still fairly new to blender.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the meaning of "completely threw this object level with the the top of the brackets", even looking ar the image, pkease try a better or simpler description. Also, did you already try anything?

Answer (score 1):

The knife tool is capable of cutting through objects. Press <kbd>K</kbd> in edit mode to activate, then look at the very bottom of the screen for the key options. In this case, press <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle cutting through the entire mesh.

Note: all the keybinds applicable while you are using the active tool will be displayed at the very bottom of the screen here.

[image: Instructions]

Another useful key for you is <kbd>C</kbd>, as this will constrain your cut by angle based on your viewport.

To align your viewport to the major axis (and enable orthographic view mode), use the numpad <kbd>1</kbd> for front view, <kbd>3</kbd> for side, <kbd>7</kbd> for top view and <kbd>9</kbd> to flip the view.

<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, and <kbd>8</kbd> will rotate the view by 15 degrees, and <kbd>5</kbd> will enable/disable orthographic view mode.

Answer (score 0):

would the knive tool be usefull here . Go to edit mode/ select the faces of your object that you want the knive to affect ( if you want the cut to go through your object, select tabulatore to select the whole object .)/ press shift + k   then to confirm enter . 
then select vertices from the edge line that you want to separate and press v to rip .

Comment: This dosn't really help as the knife tool dosn't cut completely threw the model

Comment: how do i keep the 2 objects filled then, i can't just have emptyspace

Comment: If the model isin´t a single object the knive will not work, you can have different material´s an a single object by appending the materials to a single object. To fill empty space select the surrounding vertices and press f for faces.